# Why does Sympy substitute values incorrectly?

Tags: python, sympy, equation, solver

I have a simple equation like `(f(t) * g(t))^a`, where `a` is a parameter and `f` and `g` are functions of t. The method I'm trying to replicate is

1. Differentiate the expression with respect to `t`, which should be an expression with `f(t), g(t), f'(t)`, and `g'(t). In the simple example up above, the result should be

   ```
   a * (f(t) * g(t))**(a - 1) * (f'(t) * g(t) + f(t) * g'(t))
   ```
2. Now, we use some knowledge of this specific problem (a problem in economics), where **at one specific steady state value only**, we know the values of `f(t)` and `g(t)`. Let's say they're `f(tss) = 1` and `g(tss) = 100`, where `tss` is the steady state value, which I'll set as `tss = 7` arbitrarily. These are **not the general functional forms of f and g**.
3. Once we substitute in these values, we have an equation with two unknowns: the values of `f'(tss)` and `g'(tss)`. At this point it doesn't really matter if they're derivatives or not; they're just unknowns, and I have other equations that when combined with this one, give me a non-linear system that I can solve using `scipy.optimize.fsolve` or one of sympy's solvers.

The question is, I'm stuck on steps 1 and 2. The code below doesn't seem to substitute the values in correctly.

```
from sympy import *
t = symbols('t')
a = symbols('a')
f, g = symbols('f g', cls=Function)
eq = (f(t) * g(t))**a
eq_diff = eq.diff(t)
output = eq_diff.evalf(subs={f:1, g:100, a:0.5})
output
```

This outputs
[image: ![derivatives]

which doesn't substitute the values at all. What am I doing wrong?

Again, this is just a trivial mathematical example, but it demonstrates the question nicely.

Comment: Where did `d` come from?

Comment: @user2357112 Typo. I fixed it. The values still aren't substituted correctly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
fd, gd = symbols('f_d, g_d')   #values of steady-state derivatives
output.subs({f(t).diff(t):fd, g(t).diff(t):gd, f(t):1, g(t):100, a:Rational(1,2)})
```

> `5*f_d + g_d/20`

Comment: The [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40626765/2766558) is correct about the syntax for the substitutions, but I'm definitely using your idea to substitute for the derivatives. That gives me a simple equation to plug into my system. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

sympy 1.0 docs show list of tuples for multiple substitutions:

```
output = eq_diff.subs([(f, 1), (g, 100), (a, 0.5)])
```

which for me does the substitution for the symbolic variable ***a***

why expect the ***f, g*** function names to be replaced though?

Answer (score 0):

Setting just the function name `f` does not replace it. You need the full expression, such as `{f(t): 1}` or `{f(t).diff(t): 1}` (note that the former will replace the derivative with 0).